# Typescript ambient modules are not resolved when i build project with webpack and ts-loader

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I have an Angular 9 application where i am trying to import module which does not exists at the load time, it will appear later.

```
import('s1').then( m => {

});
```

Here s1 is a module which is not inside angular application, but it will be loaded from external resource by lazy loading for example.

for that, i created **decl.d.ts** file inside **src** folder and told to typescript that it is friendly module and do not throw error:

```
declare module "s1";
```

Here is my **tsconfig.json** and **tsconfig.app.json**

1.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@services/*": ["./src/app/services/*", "./src/app/modules/form/services/*"],
      "@typings/*": ["./src/app/typings/*"],
      "@app/*": ["./src/app/*"],
      "@env/*": ["./src/environments/*"]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

2. {
     "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
     "compilerOptions": {
       "outDir": "./dist",
       "types": ["node"]
     },
     "exclude": [
       "src/test.ts",
       "**/*.spec.ts"
     ],
     "include": [
       "src/***/.d.ts"
     ], 
     "angularCompilerOptions": {
       "enableIvy": false
     } 
   }

and here is my webpack.config.dev.js

```
const AotPlugin = require("@ngtools/webpack").AngularCompilerPlugin;
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { resolve } = require('path');
const path = require('path');
const ProgressPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');

module.exports = {

  devtool: 'eval-cheap-source-map',
  mode: "development",
  entry: ["./src/polyfills.ts", "./src/main.ts"],
  node: false,

  output: {
    path: resolve('./dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  devServer: {
    https: true,
    host: 'dev.adjarabet.com',
    port: 443,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: /node_modules/
    },
    inline: true,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    //quiet: true
    //stats: 'minimal'
    stats: {
      colors: true,
      chunks: false,
      hash: true,
      version: true,
      timings: true,
      assets: false,
      children: false,
      source: true,
      warnings: true,
      noInfo: true,
      contentBase: './dist',
      hot: true,
      modules: false,
      errors: true,
      reasons: true,
      errorDetails: true,
    },  
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin(
      { 
        configFile: path.resolve("./tsconfig.app.json")
      })
    ]
  },

  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: ['ts-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")
      }, 

      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: 'html-loader'
      }, 

      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },  

      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|cur|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: `[name].[ext]`,
          limit: 10000
        }
      },
    ]
  },


  plugins: [

    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'shell_app',
      library: { type: 'var', name: 'shell_app' },
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      remotes: {
        s1: 's1'
      },
      exposes: {
      },
      shared: []
    }),    
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html"
    }),
    new ProgressPlugin({
      activeModules: false,
    }),
  ]
};
```

But when i run npm run srv ( **"srv": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.dev.js "** ) I get following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts 78:8-20
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 's1' in '/home/alecoder/Projects/JS/workable_shell/src/app'
resolve 's1' in '/home/alecoder/Projects/JS/workable_shell/src/app'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /home/alecoder/Projects/JS/workable_shell/package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      /home/alecoder/Projects/JS/workable_shell/src/app/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/alecoder/Projects/JS/workable_shell/src/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /home/alecoder/Projects/JS/workable_shell/node_modules
        single file module
          using description file: /home/alecoder/Projects/JS/workable_shell/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/s1)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/alecoder/Projects/JS/workable_shell/node_modules/s1 doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/alecoder/Projects/JS/workable_shell/node_modules/s1.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/alecoder/Projects/JS/workable_shell/node_modules/s1.js doesn't exist
        /home/alecoder/Projects/JS/workable_shell/node_modules/s1 doesn't exist
      /home/alecoder/Projects/JS/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/alecoder/Projects/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/alecoder/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 16:0-47 63:22-34 80:16-28 87:24-36
 @ ./src/main.ts 5:0-45 9:41-50
```

It seems it can't resolve include with d.ts files. I do not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure webpack to recognise your module as an [external](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) dependency.

Add the following to your `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    externals: {
        's1': true,
    }
};
```